# Vagrant up failed to mount folders in Linux Guest

Tags: windows, smb, vagrant

I have some issues with Vagrant shared folders, my base system is **Windows 8.1 Pro**. My VirtualBox version is 5.0.

The box comes from **PuPHPet**.

I do not understand why I have this error is something that is not right configured ?

Here is the **vagrant up** :

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Preparing SMB shared folders...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 8057 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 5.0.0 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting SMB shared folders...
    default: D:/Devs/Web => /var/www
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t cifs -o uid=`id -u www-data`,gid=`getent group www-data | cut -d: -f3`,
sec=ntlm,username=,password=PASSWORDHIDDEN ///d2c8055a93aac26cbde4bbf14822ca4c /
var/www
mount -t cifs -o uid=`id -u www-data`,gid=`id -g www-data`,sec=ntlm,username=,pa
ssword=PASSWORDHIDDEN ///d2c8055a93aac26cbde4bbf14822ca4c /var/www

The error output from the last command was:

stdin: is not a tty
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ///d2c8055a93aac26cbde4bbf14
822ca4c,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Before this I had the usual error that says that Guest Addition Version does'nt match Virtual Box version but i installed **vb-guest** and it seems fine now.

Now it seems that the SMB protocol is failing and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and had some success solving it.

1. When I run `ls /sbin/mount.*`, `cifs` is not listed. I only see `fuse`, `lowntfs-3g`, `ntfs`, `ntfs-3g`, and `vboxsf`. So I ran `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils` to add CIFS support [per the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#CIFS_installation).
2. Next, the `mount` command fails because the `username=` parameter is present but blank and the SMB hostname is missing (`///sharename` is intended to be `//host/sharename`). The PuPHPet GUI says it's OK to leave these fields blank and they are stored in the `config.yaml` as `''`. If you delete the quotes (e.g. `smb_username:`) and run `vagrant reload`, SMB works great. I'm prompted for my Windows username and password, and the IP address of my VirtualBox host is auto-detected.

Full details are in [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/1845#issuecomment-135941152).  Hopefully both issues can be patched within PuPHPet.

Answer (score 0):

I BELIEVE that you should open the Vagrantfile and drop the "owner", "group" and "mount_options" settings as they apply to a Linux host only.

Comment: I think that the problem was Virtualbox 5 ( dont remember the link tho)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have installed newest virtual-box version and Just install `vbguest` plugin

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`